# Migration is required due to the following errors: Property has been added

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-list, realm-migration

I added a new property called 'productsList' of type RealmList< String > to the class which extends RealmObject.
THe problem is that when I run the application I get a crash and this error message:

**io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'FuelStationBean.productsList' has been added.**

I have a class RealmMigration which implements RealmMigration:

```
public class RealmMigration implements io.realm.RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.get("FuelStationBean")
                .addField("ladestation", boolean.class)
                .addField("ladepunkt", String.class);
        oldVersion++;
    }
}
```

}

And in a class AppController I have this function which initiates Realm:

```
protected static synchronized void initRealm(Context context) {
    if (!isRealInitialized) {
        // Initialize Realm
        Realm.init(context);

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(1) 
                .migration(new RealmMigration()) 
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        //Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
        //realm.close();

        isRealInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

My question is: How should I do the migration so the app will work? I tried updating the the schemaVersion from 1 to 2 in **initRealm** function but didn't work. I know there are other topics on this subject but couldn't find a proper solution for this issue. Thanks

Comment: That's very interesting; generally speaking, additive changes do not require a migration. e.g. adding a property to an object usually just 'works'. The only thing that needs to happen is the increment the schema version. The exception to that is when you need to set default values for said property.